# How do I properly set up generic QT actions for a menu constructed at run time?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am populating a sytem tray icon menu (QMenu) from entries in an xml file which is read when my application starts up.

I am unsure of how to properly set up the SLOT end of the action:

```
QList<CMenuItem> menuItems = m_layout->getMenuItems();   
QListIterator<CMenuItem> iter(menuItems);
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    CMenuItem menuItem = iter.next();    
    QAction *action = new QAction(menuItem.qsTitle, this);
    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(launchMenuItem()));
    trayIconMenu->addAction(action);
}
```

How does my "launchMenuItem()" SLOT know which menu item was triggered? I can't make a SLOT for each menu item as I don't know how many items will exist until run time.

I can think of some ugly ways to do this, but I am looking for the RIGHT way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to use `QAction::setData(const QVariant&)` to store whatever action ID I need. Then on slot side I retrieve ID with `QAction::data()` and behave accordingly.
Note that `QVariant` obviously accepts much more than basic int (which is what I use to identify actions), you can pass any `QVariant`-compatible info.

edit : oh! btw, this is somehow ugly because I make use of `QObject::sender()` to cast triggered action back. Sorry for that, but it works anyway.